# window.location not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Lets say i am at following page on the website:

http://example.com/account/ask

I am trying to redirect to http://example.com/account/send?id=1 on button click. 
The below statement is working in ie10, firefox and chrome. But it is not working in ie8.

```
<script language="javascript">window.location="account/send?id=<?=$qid; ?>";</script>
```

If the browser is ie8 it goes like this:

http://example.com/account/account/send?id=1

How can i fix this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `window.location.href` instead of just `window.location`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.location="/account/send?id=<?=$qid; ?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work as designed - actually I'm surprised that the other browsers are doing it differently. Try adding a slash to make it an absolute URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location="/account/send?id=<?=$qid; ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">window.location.href = "account/send?id=<?=$qid; ?>";</script>
```

make this changes it will works in all browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Try this
window.event.returnValue = false; 
document.location.href = "account/send?id=";